# Change parameter style of a jQuery plugin from one line to named parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I have a little problem. I have written a plugin for jQuery, a swipe menu for responsive websites.

If I want to use my plugin I need to write:

```
$("#myMenu").sideMenu(true, "exemple", "text", true, true,
  "rgba(29, 29, 29, 0.9)", "white", "#666", true, "rtl");
```

But what I want is write the parameters like that:

```
$("#myMenu").sideMenu({
    logoVisibility: true,
    logo: "exemple",
    logoType: "text",
    startup: true,
    swipe: true,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(29, 29, 29, 0.9)",
    linksColor: "white",
    separateColor: "#666",
    shadows: true,
    menuAlign: "rtl",
});
```

What do I need to do? Do I need to use "extends"?

Answer (score 0):

You use "extend" to merge default and user parameters

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.sideMenu = function(params) { 
        params = $.extend( {logoVisibility: false, logoType: 'png'}, params);
        ... 
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: does it answer your question ?